# Availability Calendar for Finding Weekly Timeslot

Tags: collaboration, calendar

I have a relatively simple need but have been unable to find any software that can fill it.

I am attempting to setup a system that will allow a group of people to each enter their personal availability on a weekly basis and then identify the timeslot during which the most people are available.

There are some systems that will do this for a single event or do this for a single event, but I want something that will work on an ongoing basis.  Users can update their available times at any point and the event schedulers can look for availability either by individuals or by total number of people available.

Ideally, it would be nice if categories could be assigned to people to be able to filter on as well.

The actual use case is raid scheduling.  I'd like members of my guild to be able to put in what times they are available, what roles they can play and then let the system tell us the ideal play times to let the most people participate.

It is preferable if this can run on my own web server (IIS based, but I can otherwise install whatever platform support).  PHPBB integration would be even better, but I think that's a pipe dream at this point.

Comment: I've made a service for a related problem, but it doesn't quite solve your case. My service [www.spinduty.com](http://www.spinduty.com) can assign a weekly task to one member of a group in a way that ensures fair workload over time. For example, "Bring the cake to the weekly club meeting". Maybe, I can extend it to cover your case? How large is a guild typically? Maybe we should take the details on email so we don't fill this comment stream ;-) I can be reached at ursem@cs.au.dk.

Comment: It's an interesting problem that I might work on a solution for, but I need some feedback before I invest time in it. Please tick how large your guild is here: http://www.rkursem.com/poll/view.php?id=2203bf4f01a2cebf6

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at either the free or one of the paid plans of [Doodle](http://doodle.com/en_GB/features)?

Or a joint Google Calendar that all your guild members can access, edit and update with an assigned colour per member? Not as convenient as a more automated solution but could do the job.

Comment: Doodle was one of the first things I saw, but there didn't seem to be any good way to use it on a going forward basis for perpetual tracking without someone having to re-enter their availability every week, thus it wouldn't work with new members.

Answer (score 0):

[Knoodle](https://github.com/KNowledgeOnWebScale/knoodle) sounds close to your needs.  Requires your guild members to each create a Solid pod, but there are free pod servers available for those not wanting to host a solid server themselves.

Quite likely your exact use case is not covered yet, but it being an open and actively developed project, and your use case sounding very close to their core setup (the tool being subscribed to freebusy of all members of a group) I suspect it wouldn't be hard for them to implement, and "continuous weekly/monthly/whatever resolution" sounds like a generally useful option for that tool.  So I recommend to play with it, and for each detail missing for it to fit your needs [report as a feature request](https://github.com/KNowledgeOnWebScale/knoodle/issues).